# Redirect/Rewrite to subfolder, but maintain directory structure in IIS

Tags: url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have been able to cobble together the following URL Rewrite to get my domain to forward to a sub-directory. It works, but it does not properly redirect to additional sub-directories.

For example:

`qa.subdomain.domain.com properly` redirects to `qa.subdomain.domain.com/subdirectory`

However, I want `qa.subdomain.domain.com/123456` to redirect to `qa.subdomain.domain.com/subdirectory/123456`

```
 <rule name="Pattern Matching" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^$/?$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="subfolder{R:0}{REQUEST_URI}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(qa\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com" />
                </conditions>
 </rule>
```

I'm doing this using IIS for an ASP app.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it easier to declare a virtualhost `qa.subdomain.domain.com` with documentroot `.../subdirectory`?

Comment: That likely would be easier. However, that would be a solution for Apache, correct?

I failed to point out that I am using IIS with an ASP application.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it should be something as simple as this:

```
<rule name="Pattern Matching" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true"/>
 <action type="Redirect" url="subfolder/{R:0}" />
 <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(qa\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com" />
 </conditions>
</rule>
```